# How do you play an animation in the UI when the trigger is in another blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am a beginner with unreal engine. My end goal is to play an animation in the user interface that makes the word "coin" move. I have a blueprint called "BP_Coin" which spawns coins that the player can pick up and have it added to their total. When the coin is picked up, I can't get the animation of the "coin" text to play. The animation is in the widget blueprint called UIWidget. [image: Here is the UI I've created.]
[image: Here is the BP_Coin blueprint. I don't know what It's supposed to inherit from which is why the object slot for the CastTo is open]

I assume casting is my only issue, but am I doing this inefficiently? What's the easiest way to accomplish something like this?

I've followed a tutorial that mentions creating a reference with a game instance class and using that in the object slot of the CastTo, but I was unsuccessful. It would always come up with "cast failed".

Comment: Maybe you could try to get your UI as a variable. I usually store my HUD when created as a variable. This way you could use it to put in your cast (provided you get the specific element you're looking for from your HUD).

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `CreateWidget` node  ([documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/UserInterface/CreateWidget/)) somewhere in your blueprints in order to even display widget on player's screen. You may pass output of that node into `CastToUIWidget` function to achive what you probably need.

Hope that answers you question.